# How to implement custom pixelformat

Tags: java, javafx

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelFormat.html has limited set of predefined pixel formats. JavaFX uses by default `ByteBgraPreInstance` for images and canvas. I'd like to store data as Integer Array, so I need to define `IntBgraPreInstance` to avoid pixel transcoding. But only `IntARGBPreInstance` is already defined. If I use that format the pixel data would be transcoded every time I put it into `Image` or `Canvas`.

How could I implement PifxelFormat abstract class to make available using IntBgraPre format?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with pixel formats, but you might be able to proceed by looking at the source code of the predefined pixel format implementations.

Comment: @Vulcan The only constructor for `PixelFormat` is package-private, which (unless I'm missing something) makes it impossible to subclass.

Comment: @James_D Ah I hadn't noticed that, you're right. One hacky approach is to declare your custom implementation in a package named `javafx.scene.image` so that you get access to the package-protected constructor.

Comment: Yeah... I don't recommend that :). Browsing the source code, theres an internal enum which maps to the specific (private) subclass type being used, so things might break badly if you try that. It looks like they have deliberately closed `PixelFormat` for subclassing, while leaving the option to open it in future releases without breaking back compatibility.

Comment: Also noteworthy is that you *can* subclass `WriteablePixelFormat`, a subclass of `PixelFormat`, without package access. The constructor still requires a `Type` parameter though, so I'm not sure if it works to define an entirely new format. Worth a shot maybe?